For a public repo with private assets, what are the differences between clone, submodule, and subtree?
Background:
A small team and I are putting together a project in Main-Repo. We want Main-Repo to be opensource eventually. However, Main-Repo needs to use assets that we don't want to be opensource. We are currently keeping those assets in Assets-Repo. All of the collaborators on Main-Repo have access to Assets-Repo
Problem
We don't know the best way to embed the Assets-Repo within the file structure of Main-Repo. We anticipate that the file structure of Main-Repo will look something like this:
Main-Repo
|_.gitignore
|_ main.file
|_...
|_Assets-Repo
  |_privateImage.png
  |_privateAudio.mp3
  |_...

Git Clone + .gitignore
This was our initial idea--we clone Assets-Repo into Main-Repo locally and add the Assets-Repo folder to our .gitignore to keep it out of Main-Repo's source control.
This would mean that we'd have to periodically cd into Assets-Repo to make or pull changes`, but doesn't seem like too much overhead. In addition, it should keep all of our information separate and private.
However, when I went to commit the change that cloned Asset-Repo into Main-Repo, I got this warning:
You've added another git repository inside your current repository. Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
If you meant to add a submodule, use:
git submodule add <url> Assets-Repo

If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
index with:

git rm --cached Assets-Repo

See "git help submodule" for more information.

Submodule Solution
My understanding is that submodules are made with third-party modules in mind. In addition, our Main-Repo would not be able to function without having access to Assets-Repo. I read that while it can be used to keep private repos separate while letting users clone the parent repo, it adds a ton of overhead. Is there a meaningful difference between submoduling a private repo vs .gitignoring it from the parent repo?
Subtree Solution
My understanding is that if Assets-Repo was a subtree of Main-Repo, it will get a snapshot of Assets-Repo. I've seen mention that it's hard to keep the subtree up-to-date, which won't work, as we'll be adding to Assets-Repo as we work in Main-Repo.
Question
For a private repo within a public repo, both of which are controlled by the same collaborators, what are the pros and cons of embedding the private repo via clone + .gitignore, submodule, and subtree? What is the flow for contributing to either repo?


git clone + .gitignore
this is just a simple way to manually download your assets.
there's no guarantee that you are working on the same version of assets as your colleague next door.

git submodule
this is a more fancy way to achieve the same.
the big difference is, that the parent repository tracks which version of the assets should be used (with a specific version of the parent repo).


if your assets change a lot (and it seems that they do), then you probably want to ensure some consistency between the parent repo and the assets.

git subtree
this will make the subtree repository a part of your parent repository.
the only difference to "ordinary commits" is, that there's some additional metadata that allows easier synchronization with the original source of the subtree.
most importantly: you do not need access to the source of the subtree to clone the entire thing.

so for your use case, git subtree is probably not going to fly: your private assets would become part of the public repository - everyone who clones the public repo also gets the private assets.
git submodule seems to be the most useful on your case.
however, with private submodules, you basically prevent anybody to do a "full clone" of your repository.
if you have other (public) submodules as well, external contributors (who do not have access to the private assets repo) will have trouble to clone your repo, as they will either want to clone all submodules (which will give them an error, when they get to the private submodule) or none (which will probably prohibit required dependencies).
you probably should rethink the dependency chain, and:

make the public repository only depend on public sub-projects (if any).
use a (private) meta-repository for integration, that depends on both the public and the private repositories.

